# rspec mock should_receive in custom matchers

Tags: rspec, mocking, match

I am trying to use RSpec mock and `should_receive` in custom matcher. I want to catch the error caused by the `should_receive` to return proper value from the matcher and cause it output my custom failure message.

How to do it? Or maybe I should change my approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

```rb
match do |obj|
  # do some setup and mocks here   
  begin
    RSpec::Mocks::verify  # run mock verifications
    true
  rescue RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError => e
    # here one can use #{e} to construct an error message
    false
  end
end
```

Finally found it [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/9c169b40fc10a7ae495002c9a1c712e0f791eb8b/spec/rspec/mocks_spec.rb#L31)

Comment: This super-awesome helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct but now outdated. [As of RSpec 3.x](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/commit/f9caf99924758dee268b91a1039aec4e4701b107), `RSpec::Mocks::verify` [no longer](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/b789d70b76d5bde224796de6e5d2c5af2bbd291b/lib/rspec/mocks/message_expectation.rb#L30-L35) raises `MockExpectationError` [like it used to](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/9c169b40fc10a7ae495002c9a1c712e0f791eb8b/lib/rspec/mocks/message_expectation.rb#L208-L213).

This worked well for me, using a block expectation:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :expect_something_custom do |matcher_args|
  supports_block_expectations

  match do |block|
    expect(…).to receive(…)

    block.call

    RSpec::Mocks.verify
  end
end
```

```
expect { … }.to expect_something_custom(matcher_args)
```

See also the [docs on custom matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/custom-matchers/define-a-custom-matcher#with-a-block-arg).